# Magento Configurable Product Option same as sample price

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, price, custom-options

I want to upload around 1000 configurable product with 30 sample products, Adding price for every simple products in configurable products is taking too much time and later if i want to change its sample product`s price that time i have to go to every configurable product and change it.

Is there any way i can get sample products price in configurable products, so i just need to add sample product in config product and at the time of price change just need to modify sample product and it will auto change every where..

it same as it using sample products inventory i want to use its price

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this using javascript in firebug. If you use chrome just press F12 (if you have firefox - install firebug extension), then open console and type following:

```
$$('.attribute-price[id^="configurable__attribute_"]').each(function(elem){elem.setValue(1);})
```

In method setValue() put necessary value. This way only insert necessary value in your inputs. Don't forget to press 'Save'

Comment: thanks..
but This script is adding only one value in all price fields.. i want different values same as that sample product price. i.e material one price is $25 so i want same price there.. other thing is if in future i want to update some material prices i have to go to every product and update it.

Comment: Where do you store your material prices?

Comment: sorry i didn`t get your question..

Comment: Where do you keep/have values which you want to insert? Or just clarify your idea with more details. I take value from... and put it ....

Comment: Material is Sample product. With my Configurable Products user can select its Material, each Material has fixed price, whatever product is material price is fixed. With Magento every time i am adding Products i have to add Material Prices for each material.which taking too much time. and other problem is it not sync with Materiel`s default Price.
i want magento to use default material price here which i added at the time of adding my Materials.  
Additional thing is Material option Price should sync with material(sample product price) so once i change some Material price its changed everywhere

Comment: Maybe bundle product will be suitable for you in that case?

Comment: We can`t use bundle product here 1st here we have to enter price for each material same as config product so no use, 2nd its showing price range..

Comment: Could you give real example what do you want? For example: simple product: Material 1 - price $5; Material 2 - price $8, Configurable product contains N products. One of them is Simple Material 1. Expected price is. Most probably I still do not understand your idea and that becase I can't advice. Also maybe you can wait for someone else. Maybe he will understand.